# Python: a could be rounded to b in the general case

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

As a part of some unit testing code that I'm writing, I wrote the following function. The purpose of which is to determine if 'a' could be rounded to 'b', regardless of how accurate 'a' or 'b' are.

```
def couldRoundTo(a,b):
    """Can you round a to some number of digits, such that it equals b?"""
    roundEnd = len(str(b))
    if a == b:
        return True
    for x in range(0,roundEnd):
        if round(a,x) == b:
            return True
    return False
```

Here's some output from the function:

```
>>> couldRoundTo(3.934567892987, 3.9)
True
>>> couldRoundTo(3.934567892987, 3.3)
False
>>> couldRoundTo(3.934567892987, 3.93)
True
>>> couldRoundTo(3.934567892987, 3.94)
False
```

As far as I can tell, it works. However, I'm scared of relying on it considering I don't have a perfect grasp of issues concerning floating point accuracy. Could someone tell me if this is an appropriate way to implement this function? If not, how could I improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could someone tell me if this is an appropriate way to implement this function?

It depends. The given function will behave surprisingly if `b` isn't *precisely* equal to a value that would normally be obtained directly from decimal-to-binary-float conversion.

For example:

```
>>> print(0.1, 0.2/2, 0.3/3)
0.1 0.1 0.1
>>> couldRoundTo(0.123, 0.1)
True
>>> couldRoundTo(0.123, 0.2/2)
True
>>> couldRoundTo(0.123, 0.3/3)
False
```

This fails because the calculation of `0.3 / 3` results in a slightly different representation than `0.1` and `0.2 / 2` (and `round(0.123, 1)`).

> If not, how could I improve it?

Rule of thumb: if your calculation specifically involves decimal digits in any way, just use `Decimal`, to avoid all the lossy base-2 round-tripping.

In particular, `Decimal` includes a helper called [`quantize`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize) that makes this problem trivially easy:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def roundable(a, b):
    a = Decimal(str(a))
    b = Decimal(str(b))
    return a.quantize(b) == b
```

Comment: I had a feeling this was implemented somewhere. I'm accepting this because quantize does exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
def could_round_to(a, b):
    (x, y) = map(len, str(b).split('.'))
    round_format = "%" + "%d.%df"%(x, y)
    return round_format%a == str(b)
```

First, we take the number of digits before and after the decimal in x and y. Then, we construct a format such as `%x.yf`. Then, we supply `a` to the format string.

```
>>> "%2.2f"%123.1234
'123.12'
>>> "%2.2f"%123.1264
'123.13'
>>> "%3.2f"%000.001
'0.00'
```

Now, all that's left is comparing the strings.

Comment: +1 for cleverness and showing me something I haven't seen before.

Answer (score 0):

The only point that I'm afraid of is the conversion from strings to floating points when interpreting floating-point literals (as in http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating-point-literals). I don't know if there is any guarantee that a floating-point literal will evaluate to the *floating-point number that is closest to the given string*. This mentioned section is the place in the specification where I would expect such a guarantee.

For example, Java is much more specific about what to expect from a string literal. From the documentation of [Double.valueOf(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

> [...] [the argument] is regarded as representing an exact decimal value in the usual "computerized scientific notation" or as an exact hexadecimal value; this exact numerical value is then conceptually converted to an "infinitely precise" binary value that is then rounded to type double  by the usual round-to-nearest rule of IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic [...]

Unless you can find such a guarantee anywhere in the Python documentation, you can be just lucky, because some earlier floating-point libraries (on which Python might rely) convert a string just to a floating-point number nearby, not to the best available.

Unfortunately, it seems to me that neither `round`, nor `float`, nor the specification for floating-point literaly give you any usable guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

If you purpose is to test if `round` function will round to the target, then you are correct. Otherwise (what else is the purpose?) if you are in doubt , you should use [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/decimal-tutorial.html) module